# Moving data from a MS Surface with burnt out power jack

Tags: power-supply, data-recovery, microsoft-surface

I have a Microsoft Surface 3. Due to what I *think* was a power surge, the power jack no longer works. (Symptoms: the port smells of burn plastic, and it won't charge anymore when tested with a variety of power adapters.)

So given that its battery has a limited lifespan and is almost drained, is it possible to mirror the hard drive or otherwise rescue the data on the hard drive once the battery drains completely, given that I can't charge it anymore? Or is there an alternative charging solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Obvious call would be... just restore to your new device from your last backup...

Comment: Let's pretend I don't have a sufficient backup solution for this device.

Comment: You can [disassemble it](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Microsoft+Surface+Pro+3+Teardown/26595). If I got the model name correctly, the linked page says it has a 128 GB mSATA 6.0 Gbps SSD. You can buy an adapter for this drive and copy your data. It might be encrypted, but you are the owner so you should know the password.